# Using WHERE with AS in MySQL

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I am using the following MySql query, and it does't work:

```
SELECT YEAR(DATE) AS YEAR,
       MONTH(DATE) AS MONTH ,
       CONCAT(MONTH(DATE) , '-', YEAR(DATE)) AS monthYear,
       SUM(`sc-bytes` /1073741824) AS volume
FROM `r-by5minutes`
WHERE `ra-id` = '10000'
  AND `YEAR` = '2014'
  AND `MONTH` = '4'
```

Can't I combine WHERE with AS?

Comment: If you want to use aliased columns for filtering, you use `HAVING` keyword. Note that it doesn't use indexes. Syntax is the same as with `WHERE` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to hit a decent index on the date column a better approach would be to take a different view. You are looking for any rows with a DATE that falls within April 2014, and so if you limit your DATE column based off the date needing to be between the first and last day in April you will allow a more efficient query to return the desired results, i.e.

```
SELECT YEAR(DATE) AS YEAR,
       MONTH(DATE) AS MONTH ,
       CONCAT(MONTH(DATE) , '-', YEAR(DATE)) AS monthYear,
       SUM(`sc-bytes` /1073741824) AS volume
FROM `r-by5minutes`
WHERE `ra-id` = '10000'
  AND `DATE` >= DATE('2014-04-01') -- Midnight on the first of this month
  AND `DATE` < DATE_ADD(DATE('2014-04-01'),INTERVAL 1 MONTH) -- Midnight on the first of next month
```

This takes in an argument which is the first day of the month you are looking for, and then uses the native DATE_ADD method to find the upper limit.  This will allow matching of all dates from 00:00:00 on 2014-04-01 to 23:59:59 on 2014-04-30

Comment: +1 for a good solution and maintaining the use of indexes (assuming OP has an index set up)

Comment: @Noah an index would be ideal of course, though hard to advise.  There's no information provided as to what `ra-id` is in relation to the table / what the data looks like.  If it happens to be PK then my entire argument could even be superfluous!

Comment: Thanks also I learned that YEAR and MONTH are alias, and I cannot use it cause some statements are not allow to usen with WHEN.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use alias in WHERE clause, e.g.

```
WHERE YEAR(DATE) = 2014 AND MONTH(DATE) = 4
```

Comment: This would prove inefficient as it would force the table to scan all rows applying YEAR() and MONTH() to all results determing which results the WHERE applies to

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE` clause is executed before `SELECT`, so you can't use aliases.

### Option #1 : use a subquery

```
SELECT YEAR, 
       MONTH, 
       CONCAT(MONTH(DATE) , '-', YEAR(DATE)) AS monthYear, 
       SUM(`sc-bytes` /1073741824) AS volume
FROM (
    SELECT YEAR(DATE) AS YEAR,
           MONTH(DATE) AS MONTH,
           `sc-bytes`
    FROM `r-by5minutes`
    WHERE `ra-id` = '10000'
) AS sq
WHERE `YEAR` = '2014'
  AND `MONTH` = '4'
```

### Option #2 : use `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT YEAR(DATE) AS YEAR,
       MONTH(DATE) AS MONTH ,
       CONCAT(MONTH(DATE) , '-', YEAR(DATE)) AS monthYear,
       SUM(`sc-bytes` /1073741824) AS volume
FROM `r-by5minutes`
WHERE `ra-id` = '10000'
HAVING `YEAR` = '2014'
   AND `MONTH` = '4'
```

Comment: These would prove inefficient as they would force the table to scan all rows applying YEAR() and MONTH() to all results determing which results the WHERE applies to